# I am trying to update specific node on my firebase database, but when entering new value its create a new node under "ss3" node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[The node that I want to update is "txt98"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxTTM.png)

[image]

```
 editText=findViewById(R.id.editBalagh);
        button=findViewById(R.id.update);
        databaseReference44 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Registration Data2");

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String txt98 = editText.getText().toString();
                HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
                hashMap.put("txt98",txt98);
                databaseReference44.child("ss3").updateChildren(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                        Toast.makeText(update.this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to add a a node: the key which starts with (KAsr..) complete it in below script.

```
editText=findViewById(R.id.editBalagh);
button=findViewById(R.id.update);
databaseReference44 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Registration Data2");

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String txt98 = editText.getText().toString();
        HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
        hashMap.put("txt98",txt98);
        databaseReference44.child("KAsr.....").child("ss3").updateChildren(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                Toast.makeText(update.this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: same problem, it create the updated value under "ss3" + "KAsr....." + "txt98"

Comment: @AhmadSadder Excuse me for missing this.. Only one node should be updated .. Updated the answer